# insert localSorage into show/hide div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have the code below which is used to show and hide a div, although it works as it should I would like to preserve its show or hide status using localStorage, but I am at a total loss as to how to implement it into the current code.

Any thoughts on how it could be done please, cheers Jason

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  // when click on the tag with id="btn1"
  $('#btn1').click(function() {
    // change the state of the "#idd1"
    $('#idd1').toggle(800, function() {
      // change the button text according to the state of the "#idd1" 
      if ($('#idd1').is(':hidden')) {
        $('#btn1').text('Show Top Account Console');
      } else if ($('#idd1').is(':visible')) {
        $('#btn1').text('Hide Top Account Console');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Why does your `if` and `else if` look same? I mean, if a div is not `hidden` it is `visible`

Answer (score 0):

You can set `localStorage` on callback of `toggle` and you can retrieve value from LS on page load(`$(document).ready()`)

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/zt8Lm7ao/1/).

This is a sample code. Please refer JSFiddle for working example as SO does not allow access to LS.

```js
$('#idd1').toggle(800, function() {
  var isHidden = $('#idd1').is(':hidden');
  updateButtonText(isHidden);
  saveToLocalStorage('myTestLS', {
    isHidden: isHidden
  })
});

function updateButtonText(isHidden) {
  var btnText = (isHidden ? 'Show' : 'Hide') + ' Top Account Console';
  $('#btn1').text(btnText);
}

function saveToLocalStorage(key, value) {
  localStorage.setItem(key, typeof(value) === 'object' ? JSON.stringify(value) : value.toString())
}
```

Comment: You're an absolute star, it worked like a dream. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Jase Glad to help. :)